# CryptoJS giving other results than Java's Cipher.doFinal()

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript that I already have in Java. The function simply encodes a string with AES.

I tried different types like WordArray, ByteArray, String, HexString.

```
byte[] IV = new byte[] { 57, 118, 97, 110, 32, 77, 101, 100, 118, 101, 100, 101, 118, 100, 101, 118 };

byte[] md5 = { 52, -123, -23, -71, -89, 6, -59, -33, -48, 56, -69, -77, -100, 107, -68, 127 };

byte[] text= { 112, 101, 116, 101, 114, 46, 109, 111, 101, 108, 108, 101, 114, 64, 119, 101, 98, 46, 100, 101 };

String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
Cipher _cipher;
SecretKey _password;
IvParameterSpec _IVParamSpec;

_password = new SecretKeySpec(md5, ALGORITHM);
_IVParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
_cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _password, _IVParamSpec);
encryptedData = _cipher.doFinal(text);

Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
String encData=enc.encodeToString(encryptedData);
```

```
var pass = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(this.toWordArray([52, -123, -23, -71, -89, 6, -59, -33, -48, 56, -69, -77, -100, 107, -68, 127]));

var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(this.toWordArray([57, 118, 97, 110, 32, 77, 101, 100, 118, 101, 100, 101, 118, 100, 101, 118]));

var text = this.toWordArray([112, 101, 116, 101, 114, 46, 109, 111, 101, 108, 108, 101, 114, 64, 119, 101, 98, 46, 100, 101]);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, pass, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
var utf8 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encrypted);
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(utf8);
```

In Java the result is: VmivVhaBFNdJQMY5JHczcs4VQXvzH3qEswsT4PufAqg=

In JavaScript I expect the same output, but I get: VVRGUVRVQlE5VTFOQ1pLb1FFMDhUY05LQzRNcGF3UTBnNE1ZZ3luQW1Vaz0=

Comment: parsing decimal values as hex is not going to work. Ever.

Comment: But even without using Hex.parse it does not give me the expected result :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Fix the obvious bugs and post the new corrected code that doesn't work.

Comment: i figured it out. I converted the byte arrays into hex String and then hex parsed them. Not it is worknig.